# Different ToolTip text For Links and Nodes in Highcharts Sankey Charts

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I have a Highcharts sankey diagram, and want the tooltip text when hovering over the nodes to be different than the link text.  When I use just the formatter() method for tooltip, I get the text that I want to see for the links, but not the nodes.  I tried using the nodeFormatter() method both in addition to the formatter() method and in place of it, but this totally overwrites what I am trying to do with the links.

```
    var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart_container', {

        title: {
            text: null
        },
        plotOptions: {
            sankey: {
                nodeWidth:100
            }
        },
        tooltip:{
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
             //Return stuff here
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'sankey',
                name: null,
                data:   migrationData.seriesData,
                nodes:  migrationData.nodes,
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                },
            },

        ],
        allowPointSelect: true,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        tooltip: {
        nodeFormatter: function() {
            //Just overwrites tooltip text for non-nodes as well
        }
    }
  });
```

Any idea how I can get the nodes to say something like "Category: number" and the links to have more intricate details in the tooltip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pointFormatter` and `nodeFormatter` functions:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    tooltip: {
        nodeFormatter: function() {
            return 'some text for node'
        },
        pointFormatter: function() {
            return 'some text for link'
        }
    }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/romtnqx5/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.tooltip.pointFormatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.tooltip.nodeFormatter

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the solution.